# How to make PHOTOSHOP as Always-On-Top via photoshop script?

Tags: excel, vba, photoshop-script

I have this code in VB Excel. This code, will run Photoshop and then automatically run the script which name is 'MyPSScript'.

```
CreateObject("Photoshop.Application").DoJavaScript ("D:/MyPSScript.js")
```

The problem is when the Photoshop starts, it does not come to top in windows. I mean it starts in background of Excel window.
So I need to know how can I make Photoshop in front of other windows. Like for example making it as Always-on-Top via script, or simply select its window to be on top of others.

Note: Both Photoshop Script and Excel VBA are accepted.

Comment: If Excel has the focus then `appactivate` will work. It uses `setforegroundwindow` which has 9 rules, and programs must meet one. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow.

Comment: Have you tried looking? Photoshop JS scripting reference pdf has a method for bringing PS to front.

Comment: I tried, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
' bring to front
appRef.BringToFront
```

I created a batch file to call a VBS photoshop script

```
@echo off
@%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /k call cscript "%~dp0bring_to_front.vbs"
```

and it switched focus from the Windows Explorer to Photoshop. Hopefully that'll be what you're after.